# Proof: The affine hull of a convex set C is equal to the affine hull of its relative interior, aff(ri(C)) = aff(C)

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

I try to understand the proof for the following statement:
Let $C$ be a convex set (in $\mathbb{R}^n$), then $aff(C) = aff(ri(C))$, where $ri(C)$ is the relative interior of C.

I have been looking into several textbooks about convex analysis,
however, all these textbooks dont proof that statement but merely refer to a theorem saying that the relative interior of a convex set $C$ is nonempty if $C$ is nonempty. And I really dont understand how these two things relate to each other.

So can someone show me a proof of the above statement regarding the affine hulls and maybe comment on how it relates to the statement about the nonempty relative interior?

Answer (score 1):

This is really part of the proof that $ri\ C \ne \emptyset$. There one considers affinely independent points $x_0 \dots x_d \in C$, shows that their center $\bar x := \frac1{d+1}\sum_i x_i$ is a relatively interior point of $C$.

Then also $\frac12(x_i + \bar x)$ are in $ri \ C$ and are affinely independent. One checks that the affine hull of $x_0 \dots x_d$ and of $\frac12(x_0 + \bar x) \dots \frac12(x_d + \bar x)$ are equal. The latter proof is equal to the related result for linear subspaces: if $U\subset V$ are linear subspaces and $dim\ U = dim \ V$ then $U=V$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this is indeed something that I have been wondering about a lot: If I have two sets, A and B and their affine hulls have the same dimension, i.e., $dim(aff(A))=dim(aff(B))$ can we than automatically conclude that $aff(A)=aff(B)$ if either A is a subset of B or vice versa?

Comment: yes, just write down what it means that the dimensions of these affine spaces are equal. Use that affine spaces are translates of linear spaces, and use the related result for linear subspaces.

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question ;) maybe such a question was already asked in the past.

Comment: So if he have shown that $\bar{x}\in  ri(C)$ why can we conclude that $\frac{1}{2}(x_i+\bar{x}) \in ri(C)$? And how do we know that the affine hull of $x_0, ..., x_d$ has the same dimension as the affine hull of $\frac{1}{2}(x_0+\bar{x}), ...., \frac{1}{2}(x_d+\bar{x})$ and how is one a subset of the other?

Comment: In the books that I have been following they show that the maximal simplex $\Delta$ contained in $C$ has the same affine hull as $C$. Can we somehow conclude from that already something about the affine hull of the relative interior $ri(C)$?

Comment: In particular, I dont understand how I can make any statement about the dimension of $ri(C)$. I am also having trouble to write down how the set $ri(C)$ actually looks like and how it relates to the set $\Delta$?